# Approximating matrix with $n>1$ rank as outer product of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that matrix $M$ can be represented as outer product of two vectors (lets say $x$ and $y$) if it is of rank 1. Is there any way of approximating vectors $x$ and $y$ such that $|M - x * y|$ is minimal, when $rank(M) >1$ ?

Comment: We never say a matrix is minimal, but say the norm is minimal. Do you mean this? Then which norm do you use?

Comment: forgive me, i mean $M - x*y$ is "minimal difference" between $M$ and $x*y$. Maybe sum of differences between corresponding elements of $M$ and $x*y$ is good enough metric?

Comment: It matters how you want them to be close.  Do you want the two matrices to map a vector to two images that are close to each other in the euclidean metric?

Comment: yes, exactly! I need to have corespondent values in matrices as close as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The singular value decomposition of 
$$
M = U D V^t
$$
where $U$ and $V$ both have orthonormal column-sets, and $D$ is diagonal, with non-increasing elements down the diagonal, can be rewritten as

$$
M = u_1 d_1 v_1^t + u_2 d_2 v_2^t + \ldots
$$

When the diagonal elements $d_i$ are all distinct, the first term in this sequence is the rank-1 matrix that best approximates $M$ in the sense of the $L^2$ norm (i.e., $d(X, Y) = tr(X^t Y)$); the sum of the first two terms is the rank 2 best approximation, and so on.

When there are repeated singular values, you need to take some care... but not much. The only problem is that there are multiple rank-1 matrices that are all equally good approximations of $M$. (Think of the identity $2\times2$ matrix as an example.)